# Count simple numbers in diapasone python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Task is : input two numbers that is a diapasone . Then count a quantity of simple numbers into this diapasone.

Please correct my python code below

```
    import math

count = (int, input().split())
for i in count:
    n = int(input())
    for j in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1):
        if n % j == 0:

            break
print(count)
```

Comment: Im not exactly sure what the problem is. Could you include any error messages you receive and or the incorrect output as well as the expected one?

Comment: No it doesn't, there is no infinite loop in your program.

Comment: your `count` is a tuple of 2 elements (always), and the first element is the built-in class `int` any reason?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count the prime numbers in the closed interval [j, k] (which is given with `input()`), then you could use

```
import math

interval = tuple(map(int, input().split()))
count = 0
for n in range(max(2, interval[0]), interval[1]+1):
    for j in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1):
        if n % j == 0:
            break
    else:
        count += 1
print(count)
```

### Explanation:

- use `map` to apply `int` on each string
- use `count` as a counter variable
- use `range` as an iterator over integers in given interval
- start prime number tests with 2, even if lower bound is smaller
- count up only if no divisor is found (`else` clause of `for` loop)